# How to insert existing model into relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, database-relations

I often have two models in a 1:x relationship:

```php
class Child extends Model 
{
  public function parent() 
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Parent::class);
  }
}
```

Now there are times when I already have an instance of one of the related models within a function:

```php
function f(Parent $parent): Child
{
  // ...
  $child = $parent->createChild();
  // ...
  return $child
}
```

A different function takes `Child` as a parameter and requires an attribute of the `Parent` class:

```php
function g(Child $child)
{
  $child->update([
    'attribute' => h($child->parent->attribute)  
  ]);
}
```

Now if g is called with the `Child` instance returned from `f`, then the `Parent` instance will be retrieved from the DB twice. Unless we add a `Parent` parameter and pass in the instance to `g`, or alternatively modify `f` as follows:

```php
function f(Parent $parent): Child
{
  // ...
  $child = $parent->createChild();
  // ...
  $child->parent = $parent;
  return $child
}
```

I prefer this second approach to adding another parameter because the context from which `g` is called might not have access to the `Parent` instance. And it often works fine. However, it fails on the update statement in `g`:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'parent' in 'field list' (SQL: update `children`...
```

So my question is:

##### Is there a way to insert an existing model instance into the appropriate relation without the model registering the assignment as a column update?

Comment: `->setRelation` ?

Comment: ^^ my thoughts exactly additionally ```->associate($model)``` for polymorphic

Comment: Is it true `public function child()`? child belongTo child or child belongsTo paren

Comment: @A.ANoman nope, good catch, fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calling `$child->parent = $parent` attempts to set a `parent` **field** attribute on the `$child` object. However, you want to set the `parent` **relationship** attribute. In order to do this, you need to use the `setRelation()` method:

```
function f(Parent $parent): Child
{
    // ...
    $child = $parent->createChild();
    // ...
    $child->setRelation('parent', $parent);
    return $child;
}
```

At this point, however, you will want to be careful that you're not creating a circular reference. If the `$parent->child` relationship is set to the `$child` instance, and then you set the `$child->parent` relationship to the `$parent` instance, you've created a circular reference that will blow up if you attempt to convert either instance to json (or an array).

That is, if `$parent->child->parent === $parent`, then a circular reference exists, and creating the json/array for that will be an infinite loop.

In this case, if you want to be extra careful, you can use the `withoutRelations()` method to assign the relationship to a clone of the parent, which will not have any relationships loaded.

```
function f(Parent $parent): Child
{
    // ...
    $child = $parent->createChild();
    // ...
    $child->setRelation('parent', $parent->withoutRelations());
    return $child;
}
```

After this, then `$parent->is($parent->child->parent)` will be true, but `$parent->child->parent === $parent` will be false, so no circular reference.